# Download Source Code of a website

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I would like to download html code source from one web page. Can I do this with HTTP Client ? 
and in this case, have I to Generate Rows before ?
I am using Pentaho Data Integration 6, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download the HTML from a web page you should use `HTTP Client`. From the [documentation](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/HTTP+Client):

> The HTTP client step doesn't do anything
>
> Q: The HTTP client step doesn't do anything, how do I make it work?
>
> A: The HTTP client step needs to be triggered. Use a Row generator step generating e.g. 1 empty row and link that with a hop to the HTTP client step.

So you need to have rows first. For instance use `Generate Rows` or `Data Grid` with the urls you want to fetch.

[image: image of transformation]

If you just add the url of the web page you want the HTML for in `HTTP Client` the HTML will be put in `result`